# Custom File encryption, weird exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption

I'm messing around with file encryption, and I can't seem to get this to work. I'm trying to split a file into even blocks of bytes, unless the file is not divisible by 555 in which case I will store the remaining bytes in the last index of the 2d array. So to put it visually the bytes should look like this:

1. aaaaaaaaaaaaa
2. aaaaaaaaaaaaa
3. aaaaaaaaaaaaa
4. aaa

The debugger is saying the index is out of range on the line where I increment ii, but the index is not out of range... I've be at this for awhile and I think I need a new set of eyes for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Function blocks(ByVal data As Array)

```
    Dim out As New List(Of Byte)
    Dim remainder As Integer = data.Length Mod 555 ' Also will be the last block size
    Dim blockSize As Integer = (data.Length - remainder) / 555 'The other blocks length
    Dim hold(555, blockSize) As Byte

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim ii As Integer = 0

    Do Until i >= 555
        Do Until ii >= blockSize
            hold(i, ii) = data(ii)
            ii += 1
        Loop
        blockSize += blockSize
        i += 1
    Loop


    Return out.ToArray
End Function
```

Comment: `blockSize += blockSize` doubles the size. 555 times. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: Yeah wow... That was dumb, I'm obviously tired. But even if I take that line out completely it still gives me that exception about ii being out of range. I think I'm just not sure how to loop correctly to get what I want.

Comment: So is the size of a block 555 bytes, or do you want 555/556 blocks?

Comment: 555 is the number of blocks, blockSize is the size of each block.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here:

- `blockSize += blockSize`, which doubles `blockSize` each time, 555 times.
- `ii` is used as an overall counter (`data(ii)`) and as a per-block counter (`hold(i, ii)`), but it can’t be both by itself.
- `out` isn’t used at all.
- `data` is an untyped `Array`. If you’re not already using `Option Strict`, you should turn that on.
- Using `data.Length \ 555` as the block size gets you 555 blocks when the length divides evenly, and 556 if it doesn’t. That doesn’t *seem* desirable.
- Copying every block is inefficient. Use an [`ArraySegment(T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cc4bx8k.aspx) if possible.
- You can use a generator function for convenience.

So, something like this:

```
Iterator Function GetBlocks(data As Byte()) As IEnumerable(Of ArraySegment(Of Byte))
    Const BLOCK_COUNT As Integer = 555

    Dim blockSize As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceil(data.Length / BLOCK_COUNT))
    Dim finalBlockOffset As Integer = (BLOCK_COUNT - 1) * blockSize
    Dim finalBlockSize As Integer = data.Length - finalBlockOffset

    For i = 0 To BLOCK_COUNT - 2
        Yield New ArraySegment(data, i * blockSize, blockSize)
    Next

    Yield New ArraySegment(data, finalBlockOffset, finalBlockSize)
End Function
```